# tagging a cell for identification in a selected tableview

Tags: iphone

how is it possible to tag an iphone cell in order to be able to use in a selected favorite table view. i want to be able to tagg the cell and its remaining content in order to be able to display it properly inside a new table view under a different view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You set a tag with a number and by looking at UIView class ref, you set it with an NSInteger,
so a number to you and me.

`tableViewCell.tag = 1`

Or you extend UITableView and add your own method like

```
- (void) setFavorite:(BOOL)ans
{
  favorited = ans;
}

- (BOOL) favorite
{
  return favorited;
}
```

And then when you access the table view cell, cast it.

Probably better to make it a property though

```
@property (nonatmoic, assign, getter=isFavorited) BOOL favorited;
```